# how to parse XML in objective c and generated comma separated string

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing

i am trying to **parse xml** in **objective c**.my xml has following node

```
    <Item>Male</Item>
    <Item>Female</Item>

</RadioButton>
```

```
    <Item>i-pad</Item>
    <Item>i-pod</Item>

</RadioButton>
```

now i want to generate comma separated string for each radiobutton i.e. first string will be Male,Female and second one is i-pad,i-pod

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To join the string refer following function in [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) class

```
- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

Answer (score 0):

for comma, use  this concept

itemname like `NSString`

```
ItemName = [ItemName stringByAppendingFormat:@", "];
```

Answer (score 0):

to achieve XML parsing in objective-c,use `NSXMLParser` class and set a delegate to `NSXMLParserDelegate`protocal,in the delegate implement

```
parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
```

and

```
parser:foundCharacters:
```

methods.
Each time you encounter "RadioButton" element create a mutable string.
Each time you encounter end of "Item" element add the characters found so far(through foundCharacters method) to the mutable string created, with a "," at the end.
Each time you encounter end of "RadioButton" remove the last character(i.e ,) from mutable string.
Save the mutable strings to an array appropriately,you will have the 2 required out put strings in this array.